# Cursor position does not stop at root: winforms RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to implement a command line utility with `RichTextBox` in user interface. I am trying to restrict the usage of `Left and Right arrow keys` similar to MS Dos command prompt window. My implementation should not allow user to cross the current root.

`e.g.`

If `C:\Test>` is root, user should not be allowed to cross `'>'` with left arrow key.

Below is my code:

```
richTextbox1.KeyDown += OnKeyDown;
string root = "C:\Test>";

void OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.KeyCode)
    {
        case Keys.Left:
        case Keys.Right:
        {
            int lastline = richTextbox1.Lines.Length - 1;
            int first = richTextbox1.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(lastline);
            int valid = first + root.Length + 1;

            if (richTextbox1.SelectionStart < valid )
            {
                richTextbox1.Select(valid, 0);
                richTextbox1.Invalidate();
            }
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

It works for case:
`C:\Test>xyz`: when user keeps pressing `left arrow`, s/he can not go beyond `>` character

Failing case:
`C:\Test>`:  when user keeps pressing `left arrow`, s/he can go beyond `>` character and it stops at `t`

What is wrong with my code, I am not able to figure out?

Comment: You can use `e.Handled = true;` to cancel a key stroke. But this is some snake pit. What about `home`, `(control-)backspace`, `shift-left/right` (maybe more)?

Comment: Yes I can use `e.Handled = true;` but at what condition should I cancel key stroke? All other keys needs to be handled as well. `Left` and `Right` keys are my first target.

Comment: Yes, use e.Handled, only for the Left key.  And use the SelectionProtected property to prevent the user from using backspace to delete the "root".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excellent, it works with `e.Handled = true`, working code as below:
richTextbox1.KeyDown += OnKeyDown;
string root = "C:\Test>";

```
void OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.KeyCode)
    {
        case Keys.Left:
        case Keys.Right:
        {
            int lastline = richTextbox1.Lines.Length - 1;
            int first = richTextbox1.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(lastline);
            int valid = first + root.Length + 1;

            if (richTextbox1.SelectionStart < valid )
            {
                //richTextbox1.Select(valid, 0);
                //richTextbox1.Invalidate();
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
        break;
    }
}
```